# how to get next month date from specified date in Android

Tags: java, android, html, mysql

I'm designing a program where in my recylerview i wanted to display a list of items whose date is 4 days less or more than current date.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for month:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
```

This will work for -4 day:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -4);
```